# Autofill a form based on DB content

Tags: java, html, forms, autocomplete, autofill

I want to autofill a form value based on value I have selected before. When I select a product id and all of my product info should be filled. How to implement this? I want to auto complete product as well. I am using JSP but the problem is that I can get product id and I can get value in JS variable. So how can I assign JS to JSP variable and fetch content from DB.

Comment: Check out JSF and/or JSP. They help you combine HTML and Java

Comment: i am using JSP but the problem is that i can get product id and i can get value in js variable .so how can i assign js to jsp variable and fetch content from db .